# How can I immediately redirect to a different page after a failed guard clause in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Bellow is a class component I'm using as the basis for a web page. As you can see, inside componentDidMount() I have two guard clauses that check if the GET contains a zaalId parameter, and this checks an endpoint to see if the corresponding object with that ID exists. If it does not exist, I would like it to immediately redirect to a different page.
How can I do this? useNavigate only works in function components.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class ReserveerForm extends Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: new Date(),
            roomId: null,
            redirect: false
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const zaalId = this.getZaalId();

        const res = await fetch(`https://localhost:7260/Zaal/${zaalId}`);
        const data = await res.json();

        if (zaalId == null) {
            console.log("ZaalId required");
            return;
        }

        if (data.length === 0) {
            console.log(`No zaal with ID ${zaalId} found`);
            return;
        }
    }

    getZaalId = (event) => {
        const queryParameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const zaalId = queryParameters.get("zaalId");

        return zaalId;
    };

    async validateZaal(zaalId) {
        const res = await fetch(`https://localhost:7260/Zaal/${zaalId}`);
        const data = await res.json();

        if (zaalId == null) {
            console.log("ZaalId required");
            return;
        }

        if (data.length === 0) {
            console.log(`No zaal with ID ${zaalId} found`);
        }
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };

    handleSubmit = event => {
        const zaalId = this.getZaalId();

        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(
            `Renting room with id ${zaalId}
                          from    ${this.state.startDate}
                          to      ${this.state.endDate}`
        );
    };

    getZaalId = event => {
        const queryParameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
        const zaalId = queryParameters.get("zaalId")

        return (zaalId);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            < form onSubmit ={ this.handleSubmit}>
                < label htmlFor = "startDate" > Start Date:</ label >
                < input
                    type = "datetime-local"
                    name = "startDate"
                    value ={ this.state.startDate}
        onChange ={ this.handleChange}
                />
                < br />
                < label htmlFor = "endDate" > End Date:</ label >
                < input
                    type = "datetime-local"
                    name = "endDate"
                    value ={ this.state.endDate}
        onChange ={ this.handleChange}
                />
                < br />
                < button type = "submit" > Rent Room </ button >
            </ form >
        );
    }
}

export default ReserveerForm;
```

I've tried using this.props.navigation.navigate(); but this tells me "this.props.navigation is undefined" in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Navigate element](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) in the `render()` method:

```
render() {
    if(this.state.redirect) {
        return <Navigate to="/error" />
    }
    // normal code
}
```

Set the `redirect` state variable to true in `componentDidMount` to trigger the redirect.